# Nginx rewrites with %3F

Tags: nginx, mediawiki

For a site running Mediawiki, I have this config for clean URLs:

`rewrite ^/wiki/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /wiki/index.php?title=$1&$2 last;`

This works fine except when the page title needs to have a question mark. For a URL like `/wiki/Who_is_your_daddy%3F_It_is_me` the correct rewritten URL is `/wiki/index.php?title=Who_is_your_daddy%3F_It_is_me`. However, Nginx is rewriting to `/wiki/index.php?title=Who_is_your_daddy&_It_is_me`.

What is the correct rewrite rule?

Comment: you need to escape question mark, i.e. use ```\?```. Also why do you use ```$1&$2``` if you need ```$1%3F$2``` ?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny `$1&$2` is for situations like `/wiki/PageTitle?action=edit` since that should be rewritten to `/wiki/index.php?title=PageTitle&action=edit`. Which question mark would you escape -- can you please share the correct rewrite rule? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string is not part of the normalised URI that is processed by the `rewrite` directive's regular expression. However, the query string will be automatically appended to the rewritten URI, so you don't need to do anything to include the `&action=edit` part. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

The `%3F` in the original request will be normalised to a `?` by the time that `rewrite` is processing it. You will need to capture both sides of the `?` to manually translate it back to `%3F` in the new query string.

You can use more than one `rewrite` statement, so that the case with and without a `%3F` are both handled correctly.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/wiki/(.*)\?(.*)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1%3f$2 last;
rewrite ^/wiki/(.*)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1 last;
```